# What is NLP? How it is related to Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

Is NLP a subtopic within machine learning or it is related to Machine Learning?

If I want to get started at this, how would I start?

Comment: The tag description for [tag:natural-language] provides an answer to your first and second question.

Comment: This is four questions; you need to focus on one question. The answer to the last two questions are probably going to depend on what exactly you want to learn and what your background is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing):

> Natural language processing (NLP) is a subfield of linguistics,
> computer science, information engineering, and artificial intelligence
> concerned with the interactions between computers and human (natural)
> languages [...]

NLP *uses* machine learning for solving linguistic problems, same as medical research can use statistics, but medical research is not statistics.

If you want to learn more about this field, you can check the [Stanford's CS224n course](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/) lectures that were recorded and are [freely available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z). If you want to read about some recent research, I could recommend the [blog by Sebastian Ruder from DeepMind](https://ruder.io/). If you were looking for some kind of 'introductory book with code', [*Natural Language Processing with PyTorch*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34691713-natural-language-processing-with-pytorch) by Delip Rao is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Question like this may be too broad to answer.

Many people see machine learning is doing supervised learning (regression or classification.) and non-supervised learning (clustering). The data can be structured data (in table format, rows and columns) or unstructured data (text data, image data, etc).

So, if we are doing classification on text data (such as sentiment analysis), it is a NLP and machine learning problem. Similarly, doing document clustering would also be a machine learning problem.

To get started with NLP with machine learning or statistics background, you may read some tutorials to **convert unstructured data into structured data**, for example, using bag of words, or tfidf.

I personally feel below links are very helpful.

[How to Prepare Text Data for Machine Learning with scikit-learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-machine-learning-scikit-learn/)

[How to Get Started with Deep Learning for Natural Language Processing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/crash-course-deep-learning-natural-language-processing/)